# option added to select element using dom parser does not show in UI

Tags: javascript, xml, html

I added an option within the select element and it does not show in the UI.

I created an option element as a string like

```
var option = '<option value="' + value + '"> ' + text + '</option>';
option = new DOMParser().parseFromString(option, "text/xml").childNodes[0];
select.insertBefore(option,select[select.length-1]);
```

This does add the option in its html, but the select element dropdown does not contain the option. Why is that so.
But when I used the following method it works :

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.value = val;
option.text = txt;
select.insertBefore(option,select[select.length-1]);
```

Comment: Probably because the node belongs to a different document.

Comment: but if thats the case, how come the html contains that option, even when i use inspect elem in chrome dev tools it takes me to that particular element

Comment: Provide a [mcve], so we can have a look ourselves.